# Task Scheduling using C#

Tags: c#, .net, scheduled-tasks

I want to create one Task Scheduler using C# same as Windows Task Scheduler, to run my .bat (batch) file on particular time.

I found this useful link (http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/38553/TaskScheduler)

in this they schedule trigger, and i want to Schedule my .bat file I mean while i am trying to give my batch file path in tags textbox, its just fired trigger, not run my batch file so, i modify that code little bit, and now I am able to run my batch file also,

but, when i close my application triggering also stop, so, is there any way i can triggering or run my batch file even if i close my application, like window task scheduler???

kindly Help me .

Note: its desktop application using C#

Comment: If the Windows Task Scheduler does what you need, why copy it? Is there something you cannot achieve with the built-in functionality?

Comment: @nvoigt
ya you are right, but in corporate level we can't ask our employee to use window task schedule to run batch file(batch file call another application),
so, I am looking for a logic to call window task scheduler from my desktop application,
or just want to make application like it.

Answer (score 1):

You can programmatically schedule tasks in the Windows Task Scheduler by using [this](http://taskscheduler.codeplex.com/) .NET wrapper or by calling the windows command line utility [schtasks](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/814596/en-us) yourself.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you need a windows service to execute your scheduled tasks. Also see [Quartz.NET](http://quartznet.sourceforge.net/) project, that can be used from smallest apps to large scale enterprise systems.

Answer (score 0):

You can programmatically make a task schedule using [Windows Task Scheduler](http://taskscheduler.codeplex.com/)
or you can make a background process or a more recommended approach, a [thread](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645740%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) so your program still runs in the background and still has a small footprint.